# Some variants of Artin's primitive root conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-numbers, primitive-roots

[Artin's primitive root conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) asserts that if an integer $a \ne -1$ is not a perfect square then $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$ for infinitely many primes $p$. This conjecture is still open.

An easier question is the following: given $a$ as above and a non-zero integer $b$, does $b$ belong to the multiplicative group $a$ generates mod $p$ for infinitely many $p$? According to paragraph 9.4.2 of [this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412262.pdf) on Artin's conjecture, this was proved by Pólya.

I'm interested in a strengthening of this result:

**Question 1.** Given $a$ and $b$ as above, does $b$ belong to the $p$-adic closure of the subgroup of $\mathbf{Q}_p^{\times}$ generated by $a$ for infinitely many $p$?

In fact, I'd like an even stronger statement:

**Question 2.** Given $a$ as above and a non-zero element $b$ in a number field $K$, are there infinitely many prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ such that $b$ belongs to the closure of the subgroup of $K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{\times}$ generated by $a$?

I'd appreciate any thoughts or pointers to the literature!

Comment: I'd look up Polya's proof and see if I could tweak it to give a positive answer to Q1. In any case: $b \pmod{p} \in \left\langle a \pmod{p} \right\rangle$ does not imply $b \in \overline{\left\langle a \right\rangle}$, but maybe the implication does hold when $a^{p-1} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$ (which means that some power $a^k$ will generate $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ topologically), for $p>2$ at least. It is worth checking if there is any room in Polya's argument to ensure this last condition holds for infinitely many $p$.